# How can I send a message to every server the bot is in (discord.py)

Tags: discord.py

So I want my bot to send a message in every server my bot is in but it will send a message in only a channel name like

Example:

```
//broadcast hello
```

And the bot searches for the channel name general

And the bot sends a message to that channel and it will continue sending "hello" to other servers my bot is in.

So can anyone give me an example? Because of I do not know how. So I ask here for help

Comment: You should show some code, what you have tried or something else for us to understand. [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to loop through every server the bot is in, then loop through each channel in each server, testing if that channel's name is #general, if so, send a message to that channel. You can use `bot.guilds` to get a list of all servers a bot is in, then use `guild.channels` to get all channels in a server, then you can use `channel.name` to check the name of the channel. Here's the full command:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def broadcast(ctx, message):
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for channel in guild.channels:
            if(channel.name == 'general'):
                await channel.send(message)

bot.run(token_here)
```